# Exchange variables between two pages without changing the page

Tags: php, variables

I am aware that this kind of question has already been asked before.but my case is i want to send a value to another php page, and get the value from it **without changing the page.** is that possible ? and if it is. can i have an example ?.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You want to take a look at JavaScript AJAX requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX as [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2591689/jeff) said.
Here's an example:
[PHP - AJAX and PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **session** in this case

in which one page will send the data to another page

Comment: so i don't have to change the main page ?

Comment: one page will send the data and it depends that in which page we retrieve the data